# Pass callback to transformResponse in RTK Query endpoint

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a RTK query API

```
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: graphqlRequestBaseQuery({
    // ...
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPeople: builder.query({
      query: (params) => ({
        document: params,
      }),
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        // I wanna call a function here that I'm passing to this endpoint
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

and in my UI

```
const { data: people, isLoading: isLoadingPeople } = useGetPeopleQuery(people);
```

I'm wondering how can I pass a callback function from the UIs hook to the endpoint so that I can call it from `transformResponse`.

Comment: RTKQ is really not designed for something like that. What would you want to do with that/how would you want to use it?

Comment: @phry I would like to aggregate the response with help of a helper function. But it kind of feels weird to me importing this inside the api. Maybe I'm wrong and this is totally fine. So am I right to assume there is no way to do this. Everything I pass into the query will be only inside the query scope?

Comment: Importing helper functions is absolutely fine. I'd really not recommend to pass that in any other way. Alternatively you can also just leave the data as it is and use `selectFromResult` to aggregate when reading the data from the cache.

Comment: @phry ah great thank you for this hint. `selectFromResult` may be useful. Also kudos to you for making Redux a nicer place with RTK!